# "fd not available for reading or writing" when memory-mapping a file

Tags: rust

I am trying to write data to a memory-mapped file in Rust but it won't memory map the specified file as it states the given fd is not available.

I can see it on the filesystem so it does exist with correct privileges. I suspect this is either a bug or I am not using the new IO API in the correct way.

`mmap err = fd not available for reading or writing`

Here's the code

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::os::MemoryMap;
use std::os::unix::prelude::AsRawFd;
use std::os::MapOption::{MapFd, MapWritable, MapReadable};

fn main() {
    let f = File::create("test.dat").unwrap();
    f.set_len(n as u64);

    let fd = f.as_raw_fd();

    let mmap = MemoryMap::new(n, &[MapReadable, MapWritable, MapFd(fd)]);

    match mmap {
        Ok(_) => println!("mmap success"),
        Err(ref err) => println!("mmap err = {}", err),
    }
}
```

Comment: Potentially useful information in this older question: [How to create and write to memory mapped files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28516996/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files created with [`File::create`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) are in write-only mode, but you are attempting to map the file for both reading and writing. Use [`OpenOptions`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) to get a file with both modes:

```
#![feature(os, std_misc)]

use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::os::MemoryMap;
use std::os::unix::prelude::AsRawFd;
use std::os::MapOption::{MapFd, MapReadable, MapWritable};

fn main() {
    let n = 100;

    let f = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .create(true)
        .open("test.dat")
        .unwrap();

    f.set_len(n as u64).unwrap();

    let fd = f.as_raw_fd();

    let mmap = MemoryMap::new(n, &[MapReadable, MapWritable, MapFd(fd)]);

    match mmap {
        Ok(_) => println!("mmap success"),
        Err(err) => println!("mmap err = {}", err),
    }
}
```

I figured this out by

1. Grepping the code for "fd not available for reading or writing", which leads to [this line](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3e4be02b80a3dd27bce20870958fe0aef7e7336d/src/libstd/os.rs#L888), which aligns to `ErrFdNotAvail` (could also have changed `mmap err = {}` to `mmap err = {:?}`).
2. Searching for that enum variant leads to [this line](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3e4be02b80a3dd27bce20870958fe0aef7e7336d/src/libstd/os.rs#L979), which maps the underlying `libc::EACCES` error.
3. Checked out the [man page for `mmap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) to see what `EACCES` says:

> The flag PROT_READ was specified as part of the prot argument and fd was not open for reading. The flags MAP_SHARED and PROT_WRITE were specified as part of the flags and prot argument and fd was not open for writing.