# Cannot write to memory mapped file

Tags: rust, mmap

I am trying to write a byte vector, `Vec<u8>` to a memory-mapped file but I am stumped why it is not writing to the file. I have simplified the code to clearly show the method how I am writing to the memory mmapped file.

```
fn main() {
    let v : Vec<u8> = vec![0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2];
    let n = v.len();

    let f = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .create(true)
        .open("test.dat")
        .unwrap();
    f.set_len(n as u64);

    let fd = f.as_raw_fd();

    let mmap = MemoryMap::new(n, &[MapReadable, MapWritable, MapFd(fd)]).unwrap();

    let mut data_ptr = mmap.data();

    unsafe { ptr::copy_memory(data_ptr, v.as_ptr(), n); }
}
```

It looks like it is the last line but don't know why it is not working nor how to fix it. :(

Comment: What is this *data_ptr.offset(i) = b business? Wouldn't data_ptr[i] = b do the trick?

Comment: Good question but, no, as you cannot index a `*mut u8`.

Comment: I tried using 'ptr::copy_memory' instead but still doesn't write so looks like there's something that's blocking it from writing it to the file.

Comment: Unrelated: `v.iter().enumerate()` let you iterate over tuples `(i, e)` avoiding the manual book-keeping required with `i` here.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu :) That will simplify my code a lot. I think I've got the problem now; it looks like it is not writing because it is passing MAP_PRIVATE by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and write to memory mapped files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516996/how-to-create-and-write-to-memory-mapped-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out what the problem is. It passes MAP_PRIVATE by default so that's why it was not writing to it so I then ensured I added this to my 'mmap_options'

```
MapOption::MapNonStandardFlags(libc::consts::os::posix88::MAP_SHARED)
```

Comment: I won't accept this in case someone has a better answer

Comment: Incidentally, everything in `libc` is exported at the top level, so `libc::MAP_SHARED` should work.