# Calling mmap on dumbbuffer with Linux’ Direct Rendering Manager in Rust fails while working in C

Tags: c, linux, rust, mmap, drm

For some time, I have been playing with Linux' [Direct Rendering Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager), which allows one to do some very very low level graphics management. This is usually done in C, with help of [libdrm](https://github.com/freedreno/libdrm), or directly using the [DRM headers](https://github.com/freedreno/libdrm/tree/master/include/drm).

I’m trying to create an equivalent to libdrm in Rust, that wouldn’t be just a binding to the C library but would directly use the syscalls. This is not an easy task, given that there is almost no documentation for DRM out there, but I'm following [this example in C](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/blob/master/drm-howto/modeset.c) to get hints on where to start.

I've now arrived at the point where I’m supposed to create a dumb buffer and map it in memory, so I can modify pixel per pixel what appears on screen. For that, I have to use `mmap`, but I get a really weird error.

Here is a minimal working code in C:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <drm/drm.h>
#include <drm/drm_mode.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()  {

    // STEP 1: GET ACCESS TO DRM

    int fd = open("/dev/dri/card0", O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error in function open(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // STEP 2: CREATE DUMBBUFFER

    struct drm_mode_create_dumb dreq;
    dreq.height = 1080,
    dreq.width  = 1920,
    dreq.bpp    = 32,
    dreq.flags  = 0,
    dreq.handle = 0,
    dreq.pitch  = 0,
    dreq.size   = 0;
    int ret = ioctl(fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB, &dreq);
    if (ret == -1)  {
        printf("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // STEP 3: ADD FRAMEBUFFER

    struct drm_mode_fb_cmd creq;
    creq.fb_id  = 0;
    creq.width  = dreq.width;
    creq.height = dreq.height;
    creq.pitch  = dreq.pitch;
    creq.bpp    = dreq.bpp;
    creq.depth  = 24;
    creq.handle = dreq.handle;
    ret = ioctl(fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_ADDFB, &creq);
    if (ret == -1)  {
        printf("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_ADDFB failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // STEP 4: PREPARE FOR MAPPING

    struct drm_mode_map_dumb mreq;
    mreq.handle = dreq.handle;
    mreq.pad    = 0;
    mreq.offset = 0;
    ret = ioctl(fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB, &mreq);
    if (ret == -1)  {
        printf("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // STEP 5: MAPPING PROPER

    void *map = mmap(0, dreq.size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 
        fd, mreq.offset);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)  {
        printf("Error in function mmap(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Address of mapped data: 0x%x\n", map);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the exact same code in Rust. Of course, my real code has much more things in it, but this minimal one is enough to get the error:

```
#![feature(libc)]

extern crate libc;
use self::libc::{c_char, c_int, c_ulong, c_void, off_t, size_t};

extern {
    pub fn ioctl(fd : c_int, request : c_ulong, arg : *mut c_void) -> c_int;
}

fn errno() -> c_int {
    unsafe { *libc::__errno_location() }
}

fn get_c_error() -> String  {
    unsafe {
        let strerr = libc::strerror(errno()) as *mut u8;
        let length = libc::strlen(strerr as *const c_char) as usize;

        let mut string = String::with_capacity(length);

        for i in 0..length   {
            let car = *strerr.offset(i as isize) as char;
            if car == (0 as char)   { break; }
            string.push(car);
        }

        string
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
struct CCreateDumb  {
    height : u32,
    width  : u32,
    bpp    : u32,
    _flags : u32,
    handle : u32,
    pitch  : u32,
    size   : u64,
}

#[repr(C)]
struct CFrameBuffer {
    _fb_id  : u32,
    _width  : u32,
    _height : u32,
    _pitch  : u32,
    _bpp    : u32,
    _depth  : u32,
    _handle : u32,
}

#[repr(C)]
struct CMapDumb {
    _handle : u32,
    _pad    : u32,
    offset  : u32,
}

fn main()   {

    // STEP 1: GET ACCESS TO DRM

    let pathname = "/dev/dri/card0".to_string();
    let fd : c_int = unsafe {
        libc::open(pathname.as_ptr() as *const c_char,
                    libc::O_RDWR | libc::O_CLOEXEC)
    };
    if fd < 0 {
       panic!("Error in call of C function open(): {}", get_c_error());
    }

    // STEP 2: CREATE DUMBBUFFER

    let mut dreq = CCreateDumb {
        height : 1080,
        width  : 1920,
        bpp    : 32,
        _flags : 0,
        handle : 0,
        pitch  : 0,
        size   : 0,
    };
    // NB : 0xc02064b2 = DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB
    let mut ret = unsafe { 
        ioctl(fd, 0xc02064b2 as c_ulong, &mut dreq as *mut _ as *mut c_void)
    };
    if ret == -1    {
        panic!("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: {}", get_c_error());
    }

    // STEP 3: ADD FRAMEBUFFER

    let mut creq = CFrameBuffer {
        _fb_id  : 0,
        _width  : dreq.width,
        _height : dreq.height,
        _pitch  : dreq.pitch,
        _bpp    : dreq.bpp,
        _depth  : 24,
        _handle : dreq.handle,
    };
    // NB : 0xc01c64ae = DRM_IOCTL_MODE_ADDFB
    ret = unsafe { 
        ioctl(fd, 0xc01c64ae as c_ulong, &mut creq as *mut _ as *mut c_void)
    };
    if ret == -1    {
        panic!("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_ADDFB failed: {}", get_c_error());
    }

    // STEP 4: PREPARE FOR MAPPING

    let mut mreq = CMapDumb {
        _handle : dreq.handle,
        _pad    : 0,
        offset  : 0,
    };
    // NB : 0xc01064b3 = DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB
    ret = unsafe { 
        ioctl(fd, 0xc01064b3 as c_ulong, &mut mreq as *mut _ as *mut c_void)
    };
    if ret == -1    {
        panic!("Call to DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB failed: {}", get_c_error());
    }

    // STEP 5: MAPPING PROPER

    let map = unsafe { 
        libc::mmap(
            0 as *mut c_void,
            dreq.size as size_t,
            libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE,
            libc::MAP_SHARED,
            fd,
            mreq.offset as off_t
        )
    };
    if map == libc::MAP_FAILED  {
        panic!("Error in call of C function mmap(): {}", get_c_error());
    } else {
        println!("Address of mapped data: 0x{:p}", map);
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when I execute it, I get this error.

> thread '' panicked at 'Error in call of C function mmap(): Invalid argument', memmapping.rs:139
>   note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

Using an `extern` block to link directly against the original C `mmap` function rather than the Rust one of crate `libc` doesn’t change anything.

I took a look at how [this project](https://github.com/danburkert/memmap-rs/blob/master/src/unix.rs) called `mmap`, and tried doing the same, to be sure that `size` and `offset` are page-aligned, but it didn’t change anything, since they were already page-aligned.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516996/how-to-create-and-write-to-memory-mapped-files) uses a facility of the stdlib called `std::os::MemoryMap`, but it doesn’t exist anymore.

Comment: Can you add the values that are actually passed to `mmap` in each case? Potentially also add the `strace` output of each `mmap` call, just to see how different they are?

Comment: I'm also surprised that you aren't getting errors when opening the file. Rust strings aren't NUL-terminated, so `libc::open(pathname.as_ptr()` is a footgun waiting to happen. I'd recommend using something like [`AsRawFd`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html) on a `File`. You are also probably interested in [`CStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) (and `CString`).

Comment: Using `fs::File` is certainly better for the actual lib, but in my example here, I wanted to stay as close as possible to the C counterpart, to narrow the possible differences. As for `strace`, it did the trick. More info in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I used `strace` as recommended by Shepmaster, and found the problem: the `offset` field of the `CMapDumb` structure should have been a `u64` instead of an `u32` (I have been too quick copying from the C original). The actual offset returned by the `DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB` IOCTL is 33 bits long, and I was losing the most significant one. It now works fine.

Comment: That's great! When you get a working solution but one that's still small, you may want to post over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) as there's some less-idiomatic Rust code that could be cleaned up ;-).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I’ll keep it in mind, but the complete code is already 1400 lines long, so I guess it doesn’t qualify as “still small” anymore…